# Is the following series converging or diverging. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, convergence-divergence

I know one solution.

That is by Doing comparison with $\dfrac{4^n+4^n}{6^n}$

Wondering if there are more ways to do it

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the series as convergent to $S\approx2.0897$.

Comment: when the size of matter increases ppl use ratios, but then its not the right way to solve problems because they increase the density of fluids, so life is tough

Comment: You could also use the Limit Comparison Test with $\sum\frac{4^n}{6^n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison is good. Most students would automatically go to the Ratio Test. That also works well, but to me is less attractive.

Answer (score 1):

By the ratio test, we have
$$
r=\lim_{n \to +\infty}\biggl|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\biggr| = \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{n+1 + 4^{n+1}}{n + 4^n}\cdot \frac{n + 6^{n}}{n + 1 + 6^{n+1}} 
$$
$$
= \lim_{n \to +\infty}\frac{\frac{n+1}{4^n}+ 4}{\frac{n}{4^n} + 1}\cdot \frac{\frac{n}{6^n}+ 1}{\frac{n+1}{6^n} + 6} = \frac{2}{3} < 1
$$
The series converge.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to get good knowledge of the size of the terms involved.

For instance, you may have noticed that $4^n$ is way bigger than $n$.

You can elaborate as follows:

$$n+4^n=4^n(\frac{n}{4^n}+1),$$ and note that the second factor tends to $1$. (This is what you do with rational functions of $n$,when you calculate limits).

If you proceed likewise with the denominator, you have the same thing. Thus, if you call your initial series $a_n$, you have that

$a_n\sim (4/6)^n$, where this means that $lim\ \frac{a_n}{(2/3)^n}=1$.

Even if parameters would change, this solution will essentially work out.