# Using a comparison test, test series for convergence / divergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Test series for convergence / divergence using a **comparison** test:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2^n}{n+3^n}$$

According to symbollab website, this series converges. I guess I need to compare it with following geometric series (which converges) $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{2}{3})^n$$ as less than or equal to, but I don't know how to get rid of n in numerator / denominator.

Comment: That’s just a geometric series (ratio is $\frac{2}{3}$ with first term also $\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: Also, the series you compared it to is not ideal

Comment: Similar questions are everywhere: [Determine if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}$ converges](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536219/determine-if-sum-n-1-infty-fracn4nn6n-converges), [How to prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+4^n}{n+6^n}$ converge by basics test (comparison, integral, ratio, root)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261808/how-to-prove-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-fracn4nn6n-converge-by-ba)

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/879140/is-the-following-series-converging-or-diverging-sum-n-1-infty-dfracn4, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3172779/determine-if-this-series-converges-or-diverges-what-test-to-use, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/571119/show-the-series-sum-j-1-infty-frac2j-j3j-j-converges, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3423578/is-the-series-sum-fracn7nn55-converges-or-diverges,

Comment: Please search before you post a question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{n+2^n}{n+3^n}}{\left(\frac23\right)^n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+2^n)3^n}{(n+3^n)2^n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n3^n+6^n}{n2^n+6^n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac n{2^n}+1}{\frac n{3^n}+1}\\&=\frac11\\&=1.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
It can be proved that $n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\;\implies\; n\le 2^{n-1}$, also
$$\frac{n+2^n}{n+3^n}<\frac{n+2^n}{3^n}$$
Then
$$\frac{n+2^n}{n+3^n}<\frac{2^{n-1}+2^n}{3^n}=\frac12\left(\frac23\right)^n+\left(\frac23\right)^n$$

Comment: +1 but why not choose $2^n$ ? Angel your last answer is just $\frac 3 2 (2/3)^n$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2^n}{n+3^n} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^n+2^n}{3^n}$$
Since $2^n \ge n $ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+2^n}{n+3^n} \le 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left (\frac{2}{3} \right )^n$$
So  the series converge.

Comment: (+1) for the most straightforward way

Comment: Thank you Mark ...  @MarkViola